# Google Api - How To Update G+ Profile Information Using PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-plus

I am using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

which scope do i need to access, and how could one change the occupation of the authorized user?

here is what I have so far, but it is not saving the data, only setting it to the property, there is no post happening back to google:

```
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($google); //$google is an authorized client instance
$me = $plus->people->get('me');
$me->setOccupation('tester');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no write API available for updating Google+ profiles.